# Can't install generated APK

Tags: java, android, apk

I've been doing an application that uses GCM api. It works perfectly well if I use eclipse to install the app in the phone. But when I export the APK file and try to install it manually in the same terminal it just says `Application not installed`, I tried to check LogCat but it did not help. I also tried to generate the apk from android studio but the same problem occurred.

I think the problem might be related to the libraries that I need to use in my app using GCM, because if I install it using DDMS the app size is 15 MB but the apk file generated is 2.5 MB.

I tried creating a new project but didn't help.

**edit**
To generate **APK** i right click in the project android tools -> Export unsigned application Package (In Eclipse).

With install manually i mean installing APK from internal memory instead of using USB debugging.

Thanks.

Comment: I think generated apk is corrupted.. How you generate apk

Comment: Restart Android Studio 
Rebuild Project
;)
Generate APK
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically?rq=1

Comment: @no-one Please describe exactly what steps you take you create the APK, and what commands you run to install it. It is important to know what you have done to be able to fix the errors you get.

Comment: I havent added any commands :S!

Answer (score -1):

You cannot instal an APK that is unsigned. I don't know Eclipse, but I bet it does the same as Android Studio when debugging, that is it signs the APK automatically with the debug certificate and that's why it works without problems that way.

Is there an option in Eclipse to export a signed APK? Otherwise you'll have to set up something to sign your APK with a release certificate that you have made yourself.

You can read more about APK signing on this [Android developer guide](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).